# Python Extract content using xpath from HTML

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract the company name **18.21 Drinks** from this HTML https://republic.co/1821-drinks . I 'm able to able successfully download the content as HTML and open the file locally on browser and verify it.

Below is my code :

```
    import lxml.html
    # The HTML Content is available as String in crawlOutput variable
    htmlDocument = lxml.html.fromstring(crawlOutput)
    print ( htmlDocument.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/header/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h1"))
    print ( htmlDocument.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/header/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h1/text()"))
    print ( htmlDocument.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/header/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h1'))
    print ( htmlDocument.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/header/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h1/text()'))
   
    print(htmlDocument.xpath("//h1[@class='c-primaryTitle offerings-show-header-title__company-name']/text()"))
```

**Output**

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
['\n18.21 Drinks\n']
```

Kindly help where I'm going wrong with xpath ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "extract the company name 18.21 Drinks".

Regardless, your immediate problem is that you should pass a string to the xpath function. Wrap the path in quotes:

```
print ( htmlDocument.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/header/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h1'))
print ( htmlDocument.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/header/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h1/text()'))
```

Not part of the answer, but consider fetching the value using the element's class name instead of using xpaths. This will make the code easier to understand.

```
print ( htmlDocument.xpath("//h1[@class='c-primaryTitle offerings-show-header-title__company-name']/text()"))
```

Comment: The quotes wasn't the issue though i missed to type in the question on stack overflow. I have editted it now with the output. With the elements class name I'm able to get the value but not with xpath. Can you suggest what's wrong with xpath ?

Comment: Can please guide me how did you extract class name //h1[@class='c-primaryTitle offerings-show-header-title__company-name']/text()  ? Can i extract from inspect element of browser ?

Comment: I think the xpath you're using is simply incorrect, but I'm not sure how to work out the correct one if you wanted to do it that way. I extracted the class name using inspect element of the browser and saw that the header was labelled ``<h1 class="c-primaryTitle offerings-show-header-title__company-name">
18.21 Drinks
</h1>``

Comment: Thanks John. I extracted the xpath from inspect element of the browser->Copy->XPATH and tried with chrome and firefox. Both gave me same value. Anyways i will go ahead with classname instead of wasting time on xpath.